# Best practices for high-def animation videos in R

Tags: r, animation, video, knitr

The goal is to produce a video to be played full screen (on a 1280 x 800 display) of two `ggplot`s arranged vertically with `grid.arrange()`. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(animation)
saveVideo({
  for (i in 1:50) {
    data = data.frame(x=rnorm(1000),y=rnorm(1000))
    plot1 = ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
    plot2 = ggplot(data, aes(x=y, y=x)) + geom_point()

    grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(plot1, plot2, heights=c(3/4, 1/4), ncol=1))

    ani.options(interval = 0.05, ani.dev="png", ani.height=800)
  }
},video.name = "test_png.mp4", other.opts = "-b 1000k")
```

Yet the quality of the video is not satisfactory for full screen. I tried increasing `"-b 1000k"` but it seems to me it only increases the size of the file and the definition of the output.

- Which device should I use?
- How to increase the hight of the canvas (`ani.height=800` doesn't seem to produce any result)?

EDIT: I tried the script with the option `other.opts = "-s 1280x800"`. Although the image now is wider the definition is still low. Here the screenshot (top-to-bottom) taken from my 1280x800 display (compare the video with the menu bar):

[image]:

Comment: What about `other.opts = "-s 1280x800"`?

Comment: @lukeA. With your option the size of the frame does increase but still the definition is too low... I also tried `other.opts = "-s 1280x800 -b 1000k"` but with no effect.

Answer (score 6):

You are asking specifically about the animation package but in case you are interested in an alternative method that I yieled good results with you might want to have a look at ffmpeg.

This is one clip I composed using igraph and ffmpeg and posted on youtube - which offers a resolution up to 2160p:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aga9UxMPuFA

This would be a clip composed of PNGs showing two ggplot()s next to each other:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3A4qZdSf7bk

The ffmpeg command I used for glueing together the captured PNGs is:

```
ffmpeg 
  -framerate 10     # input frame rate
  -i image%03d.png  # image names (image000.png, ..., image999.png)
  -s:v 1280x720     # video size
  -c:v libx264      # encoder
  -profile:v high   # H.264 profile for video
  -crf 20           # constant rate factor
  -pix_fmt yuv420p  # pixel format
  -r 30             # output frame rate
  clip.mp4   # clip file name
```

Details on how to use ffmpeg for this purpose you may find here:
http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/hd-clips-with-ffmpeg-for-youtube-and-vimeo/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `ani.dev="png"`, you can pass `ani.dev = function(...){png(res=75*grain,...)}`, where `grain` is some number > 1. If you multiply your `ani.height` (and `ani.width` if given) by the same factor `grain`, then you effectively increase the pixel resolution of the output by this factor.

N.B.: the default resolution `75` above might be machine dependent, I did not see it documented.